# php проверка строки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, нужно проверить строку `$str1 = 'abc123';` и `$str2 = 'abc123ABCАбв-+';`

Нужно проверить так что бы строка содержала только такие символы `a-z и 0-9`, тоесть

```
if(/*проверка строки str1*/)
   $response = 'Да отлично!';
else
   $response = 'Я не понимаю что ты написал';
```

Думаю это нужно сделать регексом но хз как

Comment: чтение [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) не помогает?

Comment: вы даже шаблон почти написали `^[a-z0-9]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна функция preg_math http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

```
if(preg_match('/[a-z0-9]{1,9}/u', 'abc123ABCАбв-+'))
    $response = 'Да отлично!';
else
    $response = 'Я не понимаю что ты написал';
```

Comment: но если вписать туда `ab1c_asw` будет else. Как сделать так что бы на `_` он реагировал как на допустимый знак

Comment: '/[a-z0-9_]{1,9}/u'

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли!

Comment: `\w+` как вариант вместо `a-z0-9_`

Comment: Такой себе вариант - туда еще и большие буквы попадут, что по заданию не требуется https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения

Comment: @hardworm зачем в шаблоне задана длина подстроки? В ПП об этом речи не было. И ещё модификатор `u` явно тут ни к месту.

Comment: да лучше вот так /[a-z0-9_]{1,}/u'  С модификатором /u все становится лучше... ибо все что не utf-8 пора похоронить